# FontAwesome Icons Not Showing in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, font-awesome

I've run into an issue where, after recently updating my MVC project, font awesome icons no longer show up in IE, only. Fiddler shows the response as a 200, and there doesn't seem to be any problem actually getting the file, however, in IE, the CSS style inspector shows the content attribute as a strikethrough, indicating the style is invalid or overriden for some reason. I'm hosting the font-awesome files myself on IIS.

Comment: "IE" - which version?

Comment: 11, 10, 9, and 8. All that Font-Awesome supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around for a long time, I was finally able to figure out the issue. I'm posting it here so hopefully it can help someone else avoid the headache I had trying to figure it out.

If you set any cache-control response headers on the fontawesome file, it will not work. I'm not 100% sure why, but the solution for me was to add an exception for the font-awesome files, allowing them to be cached by the browser.

Comment: You should accept your answer so people searching for this can see that there's a working solution.

Comment: How exactly did you add exceptions for the font-awesome files?  I currently had to remove Pragma no-cache from my nginx config, but I don't think that's good practice.

Comment: In my global.asax, I get the absolute uri from the incoming request and don't set the headers if it contains the string "fonts"

Comment: Thanks Jack, much appreciated!